# How many Boolean variables should I use to represent a graph?

Tags: algorithm

If I am asked to determine the number of boolean variables required for a graph G. How should I go about finding the number of variables if I use Boolean formula to represent G?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you choose to represent the graph. There are two common graph representations: adjacency matrices and adjacency lists.

- ## **Adjacency Matrix**

  If a graph has V vertices, then an adjacency matrix representation is essentialy a 2D array of size V x V in order to capture every possible edge combination. Take the following undirected graph for example, [image: Graph] Since vertex A has edges associated with vertices B, C, and D, a value of 1 or true is present in matrix[A][B], matrix[A][C], and matrix[A][D]. Although vertex A doesn't have an edge to itself and vertex E, we still have variables for those lack of edges represented by values of 0 or false in matrix[A][A] and matrix[A][E]. Therefore, the amount of space/variables used is V^2 **always**.
- ## **Adjacency List**

  An adjacency list, on the other hand, is an array of lists. If a graph has V vertices, then the array is of size V. And each vertex in this array is represented by a list that is sized depending on the number of edges that the vertex has. For example, this is how the graph above would be represented using adjacency lists,

  ```
  A -> B, C, D
  B -> A, D, E
  C -> A, D
  D -> A, B, C, D, E
  E -> B, D
  ```

  Notice how unlike an adjacency matrix, we do not use space for any absence of an edge. The only space or variables used is for the edges present. However, this can not be said simply as the number of "boolean variables" used since one would need a different type of data structure to denote an edge between two vertices. Perhaps an integer or a string variable to signify the id of a vertex, so each list would contain these vertex ids. The number of these variables would be denoted by E, the number of edges in the graph. And each index of the array would map to a unique vertex id. The number of lists in the array will always be V, the number of vertices in the graph.